Prerequisites for learning Symplectic Geometry up to Fukaya Categories
I want to create a far-reaching plan for self-study of Symplectic Geometry with a view toward Homological Mirror Symmetry. In particular, I would like to prepare myself for being able to read Denis Auroux's introduction to Fukaya categories.
But I have huge lack of basic knowledge. So, my main question is what are the necessary prerequisites for studying Symplectic Geometry from Differential Geometry and Algebraic Topology?
What is the difference between Cannas da Silva's and McDuff/Salamon books and which is better for beginners?
What is the further learning roadmap up to Fukaya categories? Note that I'm asking precisely about the roadmap from zero knowledge in Symplectic Geometry, not the references for mature geometers.
Thanks in advance!
